# Can't get orer id from event sales_order_place_after

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I'm trying to get order data (order id for now) from an observer using the event `sales_order_place_after`.

The event fires and does not get any errors, but my order_id is blank. Any help as to why this isn't working as I expect?

My events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="PingOnSale" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\PingOnSale" />
    </event>
</config>
```

My Observer

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class PingOnSale implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return bool
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer){
        $order = $observer->getData('order');
        $order_id = $order->getId(); 
        // $order_id is blank when logging to file
        return true;
    }
}
```

I have also tried [this method](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208278/how-to-get-order-id-using-sales-order-place-after-event), that is the accepted answer from the question which did not work. According to the [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html), `$observer->getData();` is the right way to do this.

The event dispatches from `Magento\Sales\Model\Order` and as far as I can tell my code should be getting the order. Here is the relevant code from the Order class.

```
public function place()
{
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch('sales_order_place_before', ['order' => $this]);
    $this->_placePayment();
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch('sales_order_place_after', ['order' => $this]);
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the event `sales_order_save_after` the order hasn't been committed to the Database yet.

Using the event `checkout_submit_all_after` or `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` should let you grab the order id

Comment: I've accepted your answer. Thanks for explaining why it wasn't working and providing the event I was looking for. So far `checkout_submit_all_after` seems to be what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can get order id in observer, using **$observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();**. which you can use in your execute function like this :

```
<?php

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{      
    $orderids = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
    foreach($orderids as $orderid){
        $order = $this->_order->load($orderid);

       // Get Payment method
       $payment_method_code = $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();             
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I didn't get a chance to test your answer because I think the best solution for me is to use a different event, as another user suggested.